# mvc 4 complex list returning null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In other parts of my web site I'm using nested lists and am able to display and save without problem.

However, I can't seem to figure out why it is not working this time.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ActivityEditViewModel
{
    //Activity
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    //... more properties

    public List<ActivityService> ActivityServices { get; set; }
    public class ActivityService
    {
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Outcome Comment")]
        public string OutcomeComment { get; set; }

        //... more properties
    }
}
```

**View** (Relevant part)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ActivityServices.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ActivityServices[i].ServiceID)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.ActivityServices[i].OutcomeComment)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.ActivityServices[i].OutcomeComment)
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModels.ActivityEditViewModel vm)
    {
        //vm.ActivityServices <== is always null
```

**Question**

Why does `vm.ActivityServices` return null?

Comment: By a cursory look it seems valid to me. The best way to debug MVC binding is to look at the actual form values that are submitted in the HTTP request, on the page where it works and on the page where it doesn't. Usually the discrepancy is easy to spot.

Comment: Actually, look at your view code: it should be `x => x.Something` all the time

Comment: @Zruty Good spotting, however changing the code makes no difference. Still null. Any other ideas? Also, how do I view the 'actual form values'?

Comment: Open your page in Google Chrome, hit F12, switch to the 'Network' tab, then click your submit button. Explore the contents of the network log.

Comment: did you checked the html rendered in browser? it must look like that on each no of list you have to obtain name and ids differ by that index only e.g. <input type="text" name="ActivityServices[0].OutcomeComment" id="ActivityServices_0_.OutcomeComment" ../> and similarly for 1 and 2 etc

Comment: @serene does the index have to be in order? 0, 1, 2, 3... or is it ok if it skips? 0, 1, 2, 4, 5...

Comment: it has to be in order like 0, 1, 2 etc, else in case like if you have orders 0, 1, 3, 4, then your will obtain only 0, 1 in your post action method and in case you have 1, 2, 3 etc then you will get null.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial view for `ActivityService` and render this in foreach:

In your actual view:

```
@foreach(ActivityService item in Model.ActivityServices)
{
    @Html.Partial("ActivityService", item)
}
```

In a new partial view ActivityService.cshtml:

```
@model Proyect.Models.ActivityEditViewModel.ActivityService 

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ServiceID)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OutcomeComment)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OutcomeComment)
```

Answer (score 0):

So your design Razor syntax must be as below:

You could first remove all your skipping elements by adding a line of code to remove and then use it normally to obtain desired record.

```
@
{
Model.ActivityServices.RemoveAll(o=> //your skip condition);
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ActivityServices.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ActivityServices[i].ServiceID)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.ActivityServices[i].OutcomeComment)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.ActivityServices[i].OutcomeComment)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comments about the need for indexes and that they have to be in order, I managed to figure out the problem. The issue was that my code was a bit more complex than the post was showing and the index was not used in order and could sometimes skip a number. If you edit your answer with these points then I can mark it as correct.